# Требуется перевод для заметки о принятой правки на метку

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки, предлагаемые-правки

Отредактировал описание одной из меток. Позже описание приняли. Заметил не переведённую [заметку о том, что мой вариант принят](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/184809). Пишу сюда, вдруг кто из переводчиков найдёт лишнюю минуту ).

---

> This suggested edit to your post has already been handled and your
>   action is no longer required.

---

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Однако, не очень понял, в какой ситуации появляется это сообщение?

Comment: @alexolut скорее всего, сообщение появляется автору, чьё описание метки приняли.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перевёл так:

> Предложенная правка к вашему сообщению уже обработана, больше никаких действий от вас не требуется.

Будет на сайте после обновления Transifex и последующей сборки.

Comment: Спасибо! Быстро, однако. Вот только смущает ***...ваши действия более не требуются.***. Да, это правильно, но звучит странновато. ***больше никаких действий от вас не требуется*** на мой взгляд приятнее. Хотя кому как)

Comment: @EgorTrutnev разумное замечания. Подправил.

Comment: Начало предложения кривое. Надо так: *Предложенная правка **вашего сообщения**...* Ибо правка *кого*-*чего*?