# Нет перевода для «You have already voted on this suggested edit to your post and no further action is required.»

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, предлагаемые-правки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5638/176217

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перевёл как:

> Вы уже проголосовали по предложенной правке к вашему сообщению, дальнейшие действия не требуются.

Будет на сайте после подгрузки Transifex и пересборки движка.